# Define the solution set of a pair of homogeneous linear equations given by the span of $\mathbb R^3$ vector

Tags: linear-algebra

A given line is represented by $\text{span}{(−1, −2, 2)}$.

It also can be represented as the solution set of a pair of homogeneous linear equations, given as follows : $$\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 \ : \ \langle(4, −1, 1), (x, y, z)\rangle = 0, \langle (0, 1, 1),(x, y, z)\rangle = 0\}$$

Can someone explain how to derive the two equations?

Comment: Think about the geometric meaning of those two linear equations. This isn’t the only pair of equations whose solution set is the given line, either.

Comment: Yeah, I understand why those equations describe the given line, and I see that I can put any numbers instead of (4,-1,1), where a=2(b+c), then just write the vector (a,-b,c). My question is that is there any algorithmic way to find those solutions?

Comment: Certainly. Pick any pair of vectors orthogonal to $(-1,-2,2)$. You can generate those by swapping components around or equivalently by computing a basis for the null space of $\small{\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&2\end{bmatrix}}$.